# Using Union with System.Linq.IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, union, iqueryable

I am trying to use a union in my code:

```
var qryQuestions =
    (from q in db.table1
    where q.ID == ID
       && q.categoryID == categoryID
    orderby q.questionOrder ascending
    select q) .Union
        (from qp in db.table2
        where qp.ID == ID
           && qp.categoryID == categoryID
        orderby qp.questionOrder ascending
        select qp);
```

and I get the error message:

> Error 15  'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<table1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

and

> Error 30  Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<table1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<table2>'

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are selecting two different sets of data and the Linq can't understand what you are trying to do.

instead of ....select q and .... select qp

```
var qryQuestions = (from q in db.table1
                where q.ID == ID && q.categoryID == categoryID
                select new {questionOrder= q.questionOrder, value2 = q.Value2})
               .Union
               (from qp in db.table2
                where qp.ID == ID && qp.categoryID == categoryID
                select new {questionOrder= qp.questionOrder, value2 = qp.Value2}))
               .OrderBy(x => x.questionOrder);
```

The reason for this is that you are trying to select whole different entities out - ie q != qp, as they are not from the same table.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you perform the union before the ordering?

```
var qryQuestions = (from q in db.table1
                    where q.ID == ID && q.categoryID == categoryID
                    select q)
                   .Union
                   (from qp in db.table2
                    where qp.ID == ID && qp.categoryID == categoryID
                    select qp)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.questionOrder);
```

Comment: again the same errors. Even if I dont use OrderBy, it still gives me the same errors. Just is not letting me use Union here.

Answer (score 0):

While Kelvin's answer is partially correct (the two parts of the union must be of the same type/entity), the syntax of IQueryable.Union() works with an IEnumerable parameter. Try the following.

```
var qryQuestions = (from q in db.table1
                where q.ID == ID && q.categoryID == categoryID
                select new {questionOrder= q.questionOrder, value2 = q.Value2})
               .Union
               ((from qp in db.table2
                 where qp.ID == ID && qp.categoryID == categoryID
                 select new {questionOrder= qp.questionOrder, value2 = qp.Value2})
                .AsEnumerable())
               .OrderBy(x => x.questionOrder);
```